# Why cannot rewrite EIP even if disabled memory randomization and no stack protector?

Tags: c, overflow, exploit

I am following tutorial on youtube about basic buffer overflow "Running a Buffer Overflow Attack - Computerphile" and I cannot overwrite EIP value on Kali linux 2021.2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    char buffer[500];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled vuln.c with flags
`gcc -m32 -g -fno-stack-protector -o vuln vuln.c`

I have also disable OS memory randomization

after running
`(gdb) run $(python -c 'print "\x41" * 508')` I got SIGSEGV, but my registers look different from video -> "ecx    0x41414141 ebx    0x41414141    eip    0x565561e9 ", instruction pointer is not pointing as was mentioned in video at 0x41414141 but at some weird address " 0x565561e9". Can somebody explain me why? Why I cannot directly overwrite EIP and accomplish overflow?

Comment: Could you tell at which point you check the EIP?

Comment: The compiler used in that 6 year old video was probably generating a different sequence of assembly code than the compiler you are using.

Comment: I checked EIP after receiving SIGSEGV. Yes, the compiler used in the video generate different assembly code, but my question is why it is not possible to rewrite EIP. I can rewrite EBP but no EIP as was demonstrated in the video.

Comment: Did you look at the disassembly of `main()`?